# send the selected value from a dropdown menu to another page

Tags: php, mysql, list, store

I have a dropdownlist populated by a MySql database that shows the titles of books stored in my database.

```
<select id="titles">
<option value="emp" selected>Choose the title</option>
<?php

//drop down list populated by mysql database

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT title FROM book");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    echo '<option value="'.$row['title'].'">'.$row['title'].'</option>';
}
?>
```

I want the option I choose to send it to another php page search.php 
This search.php I want it to get the title and search for this specific book details.(title, price, author.... etc) .I tried to do it with  but it ruins the page.

Answer (score 0):

Surround that with a form with the appropriate `action` and add a submit button. Otherwise use something like jQuery to listen for the value of that to change and submit the form.

For example:

```
<form action="search.php" method="GET">
    <select id="titles" name="title">
        <?php /* put your stuff here */ ?>
    </select>
</form>
```

And then in jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $('#titles').on('change', function(){
        $(this).closest('form').submit();
    });
});
```

Or you could go real old-school and attach the event listener to the `select` like this:

```
<form action="search.php" method="GET">
    <select id="titles" name="title" onchange="this.parentNode.submit()">
        <?php /* put your stuff here */ ?>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Same basic idea, just listen for the `change` event and submit the form by getting a handle on the form and calling the `submit` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try as below :

```
<form method="post" action="YOURPAGEPATH">
<select id="titles">
<option value="emp" selected>Choose the title</option>
<?php

//drop down list populated by mysql database

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT title FROM book");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    echo '<option value="'.$row['title'].'">'.$row['title'].'</option>';
}
?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

Without submit button :

```
<form method="post">
<select id="titles" onchange="this.form.submit();">
<option value="emp" selected>Choose the title</option>
<?php

//drop down list populated by mysql database

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT title FROM book");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    echo '<option value="'.$row['title'].'">'.$row['title'].'</option>';
}
?>
</select>
</form>
```

Comment: There must be submit button other way is to use ajax/javascript and post your page

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in form that should work for you.

```
<form action='search.php' method='post'>
<select id="titles" name='titles'>
<option value="emp" selected>Choose the title</option>
<?php

//drop down list populated by mysql database

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT title FROM book");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    echo '<option value="'.$row['title'].'">'.$row['title'].'</option>';
}
?>
    <input type='submit' value='submit'>
    </form>
  in search.php:
  $title = $_POST['titles'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the form above the select tag and need to give the **NAME attribute** in the select tag to post the data on another page. You can try with the following code:

```
<form method="post" action="search.php">
<select id="titles" name="titles">
<option value="emp" selected>Choose the title</option>
<?php

//drop down list populated by mysql database

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT title FROM book");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    echo '<option value="'.$row['title'].'">'.$row['title'].'</option>';
}
?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

and on the search.php page, you can get the value of the dropdown by this:

```
$title = $_POST['titles'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if you don't want to use the **Submit** Button

```
<script language="Javascript">
function books(book)
{
    var url="http://www.example.com/search.php/?q="+book;
    window.open(url, "_self");
}
</script>

<select id="titles">
<option value="emp" selected>Choose the title</option>
<?php
    //drop down list populated by mysql database
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT title FROM book");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
        echo '<option onClick="books('.$row['title'].')" value="'.$row['title'].'">'.$row['title'].'</option>';
    }
?>
```

Here the list will call the Books function on Click and pass the arguments to the function which will redirect you to **search.php**

To retrieve the book name use

```
$_GET["q"]
```

Change the URL as required.
And if the problem is solved don't forget to Mark the answer.